# Could we have member of the month voting?

Tags: feature-request

It is just an idea. There could be once a month voting for "best" member of the month. It would be just a way to say thanks for all the help. Every member could for example give 3 votes for others (not possible to self vote).

Criteria for giving a vote is up to personal preference. Someone will vote for the member that was most helpful to him, someone for who is writing good quality answers, etc... Over large number of voters this personal preferences give good average.

Comment: And on which criteria would you select people to vote on?

Comment: Define "best", if you mean, who made the most rep, there is already a page for this http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/week/askubuntu/2016-05-29/ Also, competition is generally discouraged on SE, it should be about helping not winning. If you want to thank a specific user, you can award a bounty to any of there answers.

Comment: This is up to you. Most helpful to you, maybe someone that writes good quality answers... Everyone has different preferences. But over larger number they get averaged.

Comment: You would need some kind on nominations, we have thousands of contributers and they come and go. If anyone could just vote for anyone, voting would be spreed to thin to pick a clear winner. A bit of friendly competition does not hurt but IMO this would encourage users directly fighting each other for the title of "best user" and that is against the point of SE.

Comment: Also, someone is bound to get upset because they answer 50 question with the intention of winning this but did not win in the end, I can see the meta rants already. As this is a massive thing to implement, asking here is better http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This could be a promising idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big question is: with what purpose should we do that? Features like that reflect *popularity*, which is rarely a good criterion for someone's real value. Even the voting system and the reputation represent only a small area of being useful, and then only mean an indication. In short: a "member of the month" -feature brings more injustice to hidden value than it does to obvious popularity.

I think one of the biggest attractions of AU is that we focus on result and quality, rather than celebrating individuals. It actually feels as a relief in the jungle of screeming popularity contests. Let's keep it that way.

Answer (score 5):

Just **NO** - please, I don't want another one of that kind.

Answer (score 3):

In some ways, there is something already [here](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) to show who is doing the 'best' this month... (automatically based on reputation/[voting](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=month)/[editing](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=month)):

[image]

But please remember it would be better to be helping :) , not just competing against other people, or doing a million edits to everything, or spamming random answers just for upvotes etc. As [@MarkKirby said](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15478/could-we-have-member-of-the-month-voting/15515#comment28538_15478), you can award a bounty to someone if you think they have done useful answers.